# How to change redirect link after changing my domain in open cart

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

i just change my website domain from "mysite.co.in" to "mysite.com" which runs Open cart version 3
now the problem is when a product becomes out of stock and i click notify me, it redirect to my old website url[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adEom.png)

And this says 404 page not found. how can i change this?
please help thank you.

Comment: This link seems are stored to the DB. So you need, via phpmyadmin find, using search, this link and edit it. Before you will do this do not forget backup your DB in case if something goes wrong.

Comment: there's no way to answer this without seeing the extension code and where it's getting that link from - it could be the db or it could be the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your database and find/replace your old URL to the new one and then again import it.